# How to return a table that has one to many relationship with user table for a current user?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

### I am using Laravel and Vue Js. I have two tables. users and customers where both have one to many relationship.

> users hasMany customers, 
>   customers belongsTo users

---

Currently I'm able to return all the customers.

Also, by using this code:

```
return auth('api')->user();
```

I can view the attribute of current user that is logged in.

However, I want to return the customers based on the current user that logged in. I already searched all solutions, but couldn't solve it. I also tried to implement eager load but still got error. Hope someone would help, I really new in Laravel. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain your call to `auth('api')->user()` to include `customers`:

```php
return auth('api')->user()->customers;
```

If this doesn't work, what's the error that you're getting?

Comment: its work finally! Thanks. But it not displaying at the table. Before this I'm using 
`return customer::latest()->paginate(20);` 
which will return all customers from all users. Do you know why?

Comment: I think the reason it is not displaying is because I use this 
 in vuejs `axios.get("api/customer").then(({data}) => (this.customers = data.data));`

Comment: If you'd like to paginate customers belonging to only the authenticated user you can use: `auth('api')->user()->customers()->paginate(20)`.